# Variable return data with local state in Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

So, I'm using `Apollo-link-state` to manage my local state in a React GraphQL app, I'm trying to store column sorting values for different paths in global state, so for example if you're on `/people`, you may be sorting by `firstName`. Ideally I'd just query `getSorting`, pass in the `path` and get the `column` and `direction`.

Because GraphQL is very rigid by design, I've had to write some rather ugly code:

```
export const GET_SORTING_PREF = gql`
    query GET_SORTING_PREF {
      sortingPrefs @client {
        assets {
          column
          direction
        }
        liabilities {
          column
          direction
        }
        reporting {
          column
          direction
        }
        people {
          column
          direction
        }
        companies {
          column
          direction
        }
      }
    }
`
```

Whereas in Redux I'd just pass up `path`, have a switch in my reducer, and return just the `column` and `direction`.

The actual mutation is written like so (included a null return so it doesn't complain):

```
  export const setSortingPref = (_, {path, column, direction}, { cache }) => {
    let { sortingPrefs } = cache.readQuery({
      query: GET_SORTING_PREF
    })

    sortingPrefs[path] = {
      column, direction
    }

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_SORTING_PREF,
      data: { sortingPrefs }
    })

    return null;
  }
```

Is there a neat way I can just pass up the `path` and return the appropriate values, without all this dumb repeating, or is that sort of just how GraphQL is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [define custom resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html#resolver) for queries as well as mutations when using `apollo-link-state`. That means your underlying data can be just an array of preference objects, each one having three properties: `column`, `direction` and `path`, and your custom resolver can handle finding the correct one based on path.

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  defaults: {
    sortingPrefs: [
      // defaults go here
    ]
  },
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      // Note the difference in names between this and the default
      sortingPref: (_, { path }, { cache }) => {
        const query = `
          query GetSortingPrefs {
            sortingPrefs @client {
              column
              direction
              path
            }
          }
        `
        const sortingPrefs = cache.readQuery({ query }).sortingPrefs
        return sortingPrefs.find(p => p.path === path)
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Obviously if you go this route, you'll need to update your mutation accordingly.